# Edit your program which asks for a username. It should check that the first four characters are alpha and the fifth and sixth are digits. IN PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
user = input("Enter your username (It should be of minimum 7 characters): ")
for a in user:
    for a in range(0,4):
        if (a.isalpha()) == True:
            print("The first four character are alphabet !")
        else:
            print("the first four characters are not alphabets !")
            break
for a in user:
    for a in range(4,6):
        if a.isdigit()==True:
            print("The fifth and sixth characters are digits !")
        else:
            print("The fifth and sixth characters are not digits !")
            break
```

Comment: Please explain the problem. Anything wrong with the current code?

Comment: There is no question here. Is there something in your post you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

`a in user:` will iterate through every characters user, and assign it to a each time.
Remove your second for. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use the **indexing** method in string data types here like

```
if user[0].isalpha() == True and user[1].isalpha() == True and user[2].isalpha() == True  and user[3].isalpha() == True :
    print("The first four character are alphabet !")
else:
    print("the first four characters are not alphabets !")
```

and same for checking digits. You can also try **loops** to iterate the indexes.